# Thanos Store Error bucket store initial sync: sync block: iter: The specified key does not exist."

Tags: thanos

I am new to Thanos and Prometheus. I was trying to set up the Thanos components in our K8.
It is freshly set up using S3 as storage object.

Used image versions:

- Prometheus version: v2.4.3
- Thanos version: v0.8.0

Thanos sidecar is working with the config of s3 storage. However, when deploying thanos store I am hitting this error `caller=main.go:200 err="store command failed: bucket store initial sync: sync block: iter: The specified key does not exist.`

There is no data yet shipped to S3, as I need to wait for 2 hours (default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the bucket endpoint to "s3.amazonaws.com", then all other thanos components has worked properly. Reference: https://github.com/thanos-io/thanos/issues/2777